# delete a record based on the name in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to delete the record from the array based on the name but am not able to fetch the name in js and I could see 'undefined' in my console. I have highlighted the line which is used to get the name.

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-card" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="slds-card__header slds-media slds-media_center">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body slds-card__header-title slds-text-title_bold" style="font-size: 14px">
                User details
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Table -->
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table_cell-buffer" role="grid">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" height="22" style="width: 3rem">Nr.</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Email</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col" height="22" style="width: 3rem"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <template for:each={listOfAccounts} for:item="rec">
                <tr key={rec} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">
                        <lightning-formatted-number value={rec.index}></lightning-formatted-number>.
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Name" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Email" value={rec.Email} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="" data-id={rec.index} name="Phone" value={rec.Phone} onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="slds-p-left_small slds-p-vertical_small">
            <lightning-button class="slds-p-right_small" variant="destructive" label="delete all rows" title="delete all rows" icon-name="utility:recycle_bin_full" onclick={removeAllRows}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="add row" title="add row" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={addNewRow}></lightning-button>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer" style="padding: 0.50rem 1rem;">
            <lightning-button icon-name="utility:save" variant="brand" label="Create Record" title="Create Accounts" onclick={createRecord}></lightning-button>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <template if:true={displayList}>
        <p>Details</p>
       <table>
        <template for:each={copyDetails} for:item="rec">            
            <tr key={rec.Name} class="slds-hint-parent">              
               
                <td>
                    {rec.Name}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {rec.Email}
                </td>

                <td>
                   {rec.Phone}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Remove" title="Remove" name={rec.index} onclick={removeRow}></lightning-button-icon>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>       
       </table>
    </template>
    
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
export default class InputTable extends LightningElement {

    @track displayList = false;    
    @track listOfAccounts;
    @track copyDetails = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        this.initData();
    }

    initData() {        
        let listOfAccounts = [];
        this.createRow(listOfAccounts);
        this.listOfAccounts = listOfAccounts;        
    }

    createRow(listOfAccounts) {
        let accountObject = {};
        if(listOfAccounts.length > 0) {
            accountObject.index = listOfAccounts[listOfAccounts.length - 1].index + 1;
        } else {
            accountObject.index = 1;
        }
        accountObject.Name = null;
        accountObject.Email = null;
        accountObject.Phone = null;
        listOfAccounts.push(accountObject);
    }    
     // Adds a new row     
    addNewRow() {
        this.createRow(this.listOfAccounts);
    }    
     //Removes the selected row
     
    removeRow(event) {
        **let toBeDeletedRec = event.target.value;**
        let deleterecord;
        console.log(toBeDeletedRec);
        for(let i=0; i<this.copyDetails.length;i++)
        {
            console.log('entered Delete for');
            if(this.copyDetails[i].Name === toBeDeletedRec)
            {
               deleterecord = i;
               console.log(deleterecord);
               this.copyDetails.splice(deleterecord,1);
               console.log('deleted successfully');
            }        }        
    }    
     // Removes all rows     
    removeAllRows() {
        let listOfAccounts = [];
        this.createRow(listOfAccounts);
        this.listOfAccounts = listOfAccounts;
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        let index = event.target.dataset.id;
        let fieldName = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        for(let i = 0; i < this.listOfAccounts.length; i++) {
            if(this.listOfAccounts[i].index === parseInt(index)) {
                this.listOfAccounts[i][fieldName] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    createRecord() {
        for (let i of this.listOfAccounts)
        {
            this.copyDetails.push(i);
        }       
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.copyDetails));
        this.displayList = true;
        console.log(this.displayList);
        this.accountObject = {};
        console.log('object callled');
        let listOfAccounts = [];
        this.createRow(listOfAccounts);
        this.listOfAccounts = listOfAccounts;
        console.log('final method');        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let toBeDeletedRec = event.target.value;
```

`event.target.value` isn't set to anything. You never set the name to any attribute on the component, so you couldn't find it by name.

I recommend using a data attribute instead:

```
let toBeDeletedRec = event.target.dataset.index
```

And:

```
<lightning-button-icon ... data-index={rec.index} onclick={removeRow}
</lightning-button-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I try to delete with index I have another issue that's why tried to delete with name. At first, I add 2 rows and then save them to the copydetails array and again I add 2 rows and save them to the same array but when I delete  the 4th row it automatically deletes the 2nd row also since both rows have index '2'

Comment: That sounds like an implementation issue, the way you identify your rows needs to be unique or else you encounter the problem you currently have. Take a look at the [iterator attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_lists) if you want to track the index (position) of an item in a for:each - which is likely the easiest way to accomplish this if they don't have a unique identifier elsewhere.

Comment: @Sumosales Yes, you can't reuse indexes (and names would be equally unreliable--the user can enter the same name twice). Here's a [fixed version](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/NEKUhP3zWPLWsyxF4qFq/src/inputTable.js?p=stories) for you to look at.

Comment: @sfdcfox- With this code, when I add 2 rows at a time which will get saved and displayed in copydetails array and if I add 2 rows next time it is overriding the previous value existing in copydetails array and displays the new values only.. Also, the delete functionality on copydetails is not working

Comment: @sfdcfox - is there any way can we include an additional column to the array when we copy one array value to another array? eg: when am copying listOfAccounts array to copydetails I have to add one more column like 'Id' in copydetails so based on Id value I can delete the row

Comment: @Sumosales I didn't fix any extra functionality except the delete row feature at the top. However, since you asked, I've updated the demo to include proper functionality for the copyDetails variable as well; it's basically just copy-paste from the top part. See the updated version in the previous link.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks much for your help and effort!